# jquery, move element to closest div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to move some `span` elements to closest `div`. I found the solution to my problem but it does not work for me. I have some Html code:

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a><span>Some info</span></a>
  </li>
  <div class="cl1">...</div>

  <li>
    <a><span>Some info 2</span><a>
  </li>
  <div class="cl1">
     ...
  </div>
...
</ul>
```

and to move `<span>` like this:

```
$('span').each(function () {
  $(this).parent().parent().closest('.cl1').append(this);
})
```

but nothing happened. Any help would certainly be appreciated

Comment: The [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method looks through the ancestors, not the siblings of ancestors; and any elements other than `<li>` are invalid children of a `<ul>`, or `<ol>`, element.

Comment: So wait. First, your anchor tags aren't closed properly, which causes headaches. Second, you have div tags and list item tags intermixed as children of an unordered list. And you're wondering why things are not going as you expect?

Answer (score 0):

1. you can't put a `div` in a `ul`, only `li`'s.
2. your html has to be valid  (`a`'s, `ul` need to be closed)
3. Closest searches anscetors, not siblings.
4. since your markup is not valid as is, i'm not sure if you want the divs in the list or not. This example removes them from the lis, which breaks the list into two lists.

```js
$('button').click(function() {

  $('span').each(function() {
    var $div = $(this).closest('ul').siblings('.cl1');
    $(this).clone().appendTo($div);
    $(this).remove();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a><span>Some info</span></a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="cl1">...</div>

<ul>
  <li>
    <a><span>Some info 2</span></a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="cl1">...</div>

<button>Do Stuff</button>
```